# Drooping peace plant

Tags: plant-recommendations

I split my peace plant about a week ago. Ever since splitting all pieces are drooping. It has been at least a week. Do they need more time or are they dying.

Comment: Did you just split it in half, then replant the half rootballs immediately? What implement did you use to separate it with?

Comment: does it have enough life support (nitrogen)?

Comment: can you add a picture?

Comment: Bamboo, I did split in half separated with my gloved hands only, and planted immediately. It's now 2 whole weeks and they are still drooping. There doesn't seem to be any dying leaves as of now.

Comment: Kevinsky, I tried to add a picture but the site told me it was too big and I don't know how to make it smaller.

Comment: Black thumb, how do I check the nitrogen or how do I know if it's  getting enough?